# How to call a function within a function without passing any variables into function Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have the following code but it keeps throwing a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nineAM' of undefined"

Usually in OOP I would declare a Class and then have separate methods within the class. I wanted to do a similar thing using JS but not too sure whether this is possible.

```
function SetBtnToEcr () {
    document.getElementById("depart").value = "Test 1";
    document.getElementById("arrive").value = "Test2";

    GetTodaysDate();
    new (GetHour()).nineAM();
}

function SetDeptTime () {
    SetBtnToECR();
}

function GetHour(){
    function nineAM () {
        document.getElementById("hour").selectedIndex = "09";
    }

    function fiveThirtyPM(){
        document.getElementById("hour").selectedIndex = "17";
        document.getElementById("minute").selectedIndex = "30";
    }

    function twoFifteenPM(){
        document.getElementById("hour").selectedIndex = "14";
        document.getElementById("minute").selectedIndex = "15";
    }
}
```

I have looked online but in all other examples I have seen parameters being passed into the methods or just methods which return a string and then use this.methodName to return their desired string. However I do not want anything to be returned, I just want to set the hour to be 9am.

Comment: `GetHour` function doesn't return anything ... perhaps you wanted something like `return {nineAM:nineAM, fiveThirtyPM:fiveThirtyPM, twoFifteenPM:twoFifteenPM};` at the end of `GetHour` function

Answer (score 2):

If you intended `GetHour` to be a [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function) (similar to a class) it should be like:

```
function GetHour(){
    this.nineAM = function () {
        document.getElementById("hour").selectedIndex = "09";
    }
    // ...
}
```

And used like:

```
new GetHour().nineAM();
```

Or if you use ES2015 or later, you can define using the [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

```
class GetHour {
    nineAM() {
        document.getElementById("hour").selectedIndex = "09";
    }
}
new GetHour().nineAM();
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to return from your function, e.g.

```
function GetHour(){
    function nineAM () {
        document.getElementById("hour").selectedIndex = "09";
    }

    function fiveThirtyPM(){
        document.getElementById("hour").selectedIndex = "17";
        document.getElementById("minute").selectedIndex = "30";
    }

    function twoFifteenPM(){
        document.getElementById("hour").selectedIndex = "14";
        document.getElementById("minute").selectedIndex = "15";
    }

    return {
      nineAM,
      fiveThirtyPM,
      twoFifteenPM
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a constructor function, with public properties and methods being defined with the `this` keyword, and instance being created using the `new` keyword.

As of ES2015, you can use the familiar OOP type [class syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

```
class getHour{
   nineAM () {
       document.getElementById("hour").selectedIndex = "09";
    }

   fiveThirtyPM(){
      document.getElementById("hour").selectedIndex = "17";
      document.getElementById("minute").selectedIndex = "30";
   }

   twoFifteenPM(){
      document.getElementById("hour").selectedIndex = "14";
      document.getElementById("minute").selectedIndex = "15";
   }

}
```

And then access the methods from an instance of the getHour class.

```
let gh = new getHour();
gh.nineAM();
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you begin down this road, it would be good to read Eric Elliot's (vert opinionated) take on the ongoing debate about Constructors, Classes and Factories in JavaScript.

https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-vs-constructor-functions-vs-classes-2f22ceddf33e

@baao's answer describes how to achieve what you want using a factory. As Eric argues in his article, factories are the simplest solution. Definitely worth checking out.